# SSO to Apps on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services

Can someone help me with my understanding?

So i understand how one can use ADFS and SAML to provide SSO access to the Console via IAM. However im not as clear how this can be done at the application level

So take MS Dynamics as an example. It will be on an EC2 instance which is on a domain controller hosted in the VPC (for mgt etc). However the users themselves will be in an on-prem AD server and we'd want to authenticate users accessing the dynamics web front end with that on-prem AD server. Is this as simple as setting up ADFS between the two sites and configuring the app itself to use ADFS / SAML for claims based authentication?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For application level support, it depends on the ability of the app to support claims based/SAML authentication. CRM supports ADFS configuration. You have one of 2 choices

1. You can hook it up directly to your on-premises ADFS if it is really about just providing access to your corporate employees. If it requires partner access that ADFS can still federate to other ADFS/IDP organizations.
2. You can set one up in AWS next to or on the DC that it has and treat it as a Federation Provider and then set up trust to the corporate ADFS where the users live.

I'd recommend #1 as it is simpler. Go with #2 only if you are operating this as a different company or you are building multiple server apps in this AWS site that require local ADFS for things like server to server communication.

Thanks
//Sam